# Custom CIFilter with SpriteKit

Tags: sprite-kit, core-image, cifilter, skeffectnode

I'm trying to implement my own custom `CIFilter` with SpriteKit. What I would like to achieve is to use my custom `CIFilter` as the filter on a `SKEffectNode`.

I wrote a very simple test filter (just returns the pixelValue), and it works fine in `QuartzComposer`.

I followed [the dev guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_custom_filters/ci_custom_filters.html) to write a `CIFilter` subclass, register the filter, and provide `filterWithName` and `outputImage` implementations, as well initialize and init.

However when I try using the `CIFilter` on my `SKEffectNode`, I don't get an output image (just a blank image - blank as in `clearColor` filled).

I don't think anything is wrong with my `SKEffectNode` setup because if I switch to another (built-in) `CIFilter` everything works as expected.

I also don't think there is anything wrong with the .cikernel since it runs fine in Quartz Composer (also it's really just one line that returns the pixelValue from the sample...)

I set breakpoints in the init and initialize of my `CIFilter` subclass, both get called, the kernel gets initialized with the correct code string, and everything since to be going fine.

However my output remains infuriatingly blank ...

Has anybody been successful in using custom `CIFilters` on `SKEffectNodes` ?

Thanks!

EDIT: forgot to mention that I do call `[MyFilterSubclass class]` to intialize it prior to using it, and I also set a breakpoint in `-(CIImage *)outputImage` and it does get called everyframe, so it looks like the filter is setup correctly and it's computing a result every frame, but that result somehow doesn't get used by the `SKEffectNode`... help :( !

Comment: 1. Which platform are you on? Core Image only supports custom kernels on OS X. 2. Have you made sure your filter class works outside of Sprite Kit?

Comment: I'm on OSX 9. Good point about checking if the class works outside of sprite kit, hadn't thought of that! (duh!). Will try it and update the post (right after Xmas :D)

Merry Xmas everyone!